# Как на одной странице включить два bxslider с разными настройками?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Собственно, вопрос. Мне нужны два слайдера с разными настройками.Как это сделать?Первый у меня имеет такой код html:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
                <li>
```

и js :

```
function bxslider() {
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        infiniteLoop: false
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не показали html второго слайдера, но предположим он у вас такой:

```
<ul class="bxslider slider2">
            <li>
```

Тогда для инициализации второго слайдера, вам нужен такой js код:

```
$('.bxslider.slider2').bxSlider({
    infiniteLoop: false
});
```

К сожалению я не знаю, что это за функция и в какой момент она срабатывает: `function bxslider()`, но в большинстве случаем слайдеры инициализуруют так, и при загрузке страницы у вас запустятся оба слайдера:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.bxslider.slider1').bxSlider({
    infiniteLoop: false
  });
  $('.bxslider.slider2').bxSlider({
    infiniteLoop: false
  });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо
кода второго нет)
Точнее был, но я его удалил
Хорошо, а стили как ворочать для другого?
Подключен общий файл bxslider

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов, подправил немного ответ. Кастомизация слайдеров может быть двух видов. Первый, на уровне возможностей библиотеки github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4 в момент инициализации. Второй, на уровне css, у вас есть классы, на которые вы можете повесить свои измнение

Comment: О, тут мне сасс пригодится со своей вложенностью. Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Два слайдера:

```
<ul class="bxslider-1">
  ...
<ul>
<ul class="bxslider-2">
  ...
<ul>
```

Два обращения к каждому:

```
function bxslider() {
    $('.bxslider-1').bxSlider({
        infiniteLoop: false
    });
}
function bxslider() {
    $('.bxslider-2').bxSlider({
        infiniteLoop: true
    });
}
```

То бишь, давайте какой-угодно класс своим слайдерам в html и по этим классам обращайтесь к ним, чтобы инициализировать и давать разные настройки через API

Comment: Понял, спасибо за помощь